# Is it possible to edit the expiration of JWT token?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am new to the JWT world, and would be happy to get some help in here.
I have an app that works perfectly with this wonderful solution, but found a little issue with extending the expiration of the token when the user logs in to my app.

In other words, I want to renew the expiration each time that the user access my app with his former JWT.

Is there any solution to do that without overwritting the former token and reissuing a new one?

Thanks!

Comment: The main idea of JWT is in preventing changes in payload without keeping the rest same. So, no, you must regenerate hash part again, which effectevly means you gonna regenerate whole token. Well, even change in payload will make JWT token different because payload is stored inside.

Comment: What it sounds like you want is a refresh token: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

Comment: @user28434 so based on your answer, what will be the best practice for me? What is the standards of doing that? Regenerating token anytime?

Comment: You should use refresh token system, as in @ThisIsNoZaku comment. Client can get expiration time from the token, so it should refresh/request new one when it's due.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any solution to do that without overwritting the former token and reissuing a new one?

No. Once the token is signed, any modifications to its content will invalidate the token.