# Modifying a jwt

Tags: express, jwt, express-jwt

I'm getting a `'token expired'` error when making REST requests to a test app. I have the secrets being used to generate jwt tokens. I've tried decoding the jwt at `jwt.io`, bumping the `exp` value of payload a little, and decoding it again, but I get a `'invalid signature'` error when using this token.

How do I modify this jwt token for which I have the secret available?

Edit:

jwt:

```
  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1OTk4ZDliZTEyZWE2YzE4MjRiNzQzMDQiLCJpYXQiOjE1MDMyODkyOTQsImV4cCI6MTUwMzM3NTY5NCwiYXVkIjoiQ0xJRU5UX0lEIn0.IBx6iwAlNy-VegGzbxel44-vVB1d7QEbBiv8r98tq8w
```

secret:

```
CLIENT_SECRET
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to edit the expiration of JWT token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900463/is-it-possible-to-edit-the-expiration-of-jwt-token)

Comment: it should work when you have the correct secret (assuming it's a symmetric alg, eg. HS256).  If you paste the secret first and then the original token, do you get "signature verified" on jwt.io?

Comment: @joe the suggested duplicate is not an answer to this question because the OP says he has the secret that was used to sign the token and with that secret (in case of a symmetric alg) one should be able to produce a valid token.

Comment: @jps yes I do get that message

Comment: the important part is that you **first** paste the secret and **then** paste the token. Can you add the original token and secret to your question, so we can check?

Comment: @jps I've added that info to the question.

Comment: What is the point to know the secret key? If you know secret key, you can create a new token when you get `token expired` or even generate a new token every time you make an api call.

Comment: @saga: The token can't be validated the the secret "CLIENT_SECRET" , if you tried with exactly that secret you produce an invalid token that the server doesn't accpect.

Comment: @SuleymanSah: it's certainly not a production scenario we're talking about here, but for the sake of learning and undertanding certain mechanismns it's perfectly fine to play around and see what happens.

Comment: @saga have you been able to solve your problem?

Comment: @jps No. It looks like `CLIENT_SECRET` isn't the secret of this jwt.